# Coroutine Scoping with Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a network call that gets some LiveData. The LiveData is observed with my Fragment's lifecycle owner so UI updates are safe. But does the coroutine call I make also need to be scoped to the fragment's lifecycleowner? In other words, does it matter which one of these I use?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch
```

or

```
fragment.lifecycleScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{}` is a **CoroutineScope** that launches all coroutines in it and return a *Coroutine Job*.
But you need to call `cancel()` to stop all lauched coroutines in this scope if your activity/fragment/viewmodel is destroyed. If any coroutine keep running in background after that, it may leads to memory leaks.

`fragment.lifecycleScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO){}` is a **Lifecycle-aware Coroutine Scope** so any coroutine launched in this scope is automatically canceled if lifecycle (activity/fragment/viewmodel) is destroyed.

It's better to use coroutines with `lifecycleScope` so you don't have to manage the lifecycle of a *Coroutine Job*

Comment: What about `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`? Is there any difference?

Comment: They are the same, `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` is a Lifecycle-aware Coroutine Scope too. You can also use `viewModelScope`, but this scope is binding with ViewModel Lifecycle
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware